# jquery fade out display:none

Tags: jquery, fadein, fade, fadeout

Why doesn't my jQuery fade out work. If I replace Out with In and None with Inline it will fade in fine but it won't fade out. Any ideas?

```
$(this).find(".hover").fadeOut("slow").css({display:"none"});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue is the `.css({ display : 'none' })`, you don't need this code there since `fadeOut` will hide it once it's complete. Try using this code:

```
$(this).find(".hover").fadeOut("slow");
```

Or if you must have the hide... Try this code (fadeOut's 2nd parameter is a callback function that is ran AFTER fadeOut is complete)

```
$(this).find(".hover").fadeOut("slow", function () {
    $(this).css({display:"none"});
});
```

Comment: That first one worked fine, I was thinking that but I thought it would remove the class from the page so it wouldnt add it again when I hover

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(".hover").fadeOut("slow", function(){
              alert("fadeout complete!!!");
     });
});
```

that should work havent tested though just coded it. Like McHerbie said when fadeOut is done the display property is set to none. I dont see why your using find either.

Comment: The OP is using `find` to only get elements with the class 'hover' that are children of `this` (whatever `this` is).

Comment: Exactly what Rocket said. I assume you were suggesting doing this: `$(".hover").fadeIn("slow")` but then if i had 2 or more on the page they would all fade in when I only want one to fade in